# Get a user's OU group based on a file that was created

Tags: powershell

I am creating a list of all files in a location that show owner, file path, creation time, last write time, and last access time.  I want to also add the user's OU group from AD to the list as well.  How can I incorporate that?  Here is my code:

```
$Path = "C:\Users\Mark\Documents"
$MyFile = "C:\Test.csv"
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Select-Object @{N='Owner';E={$_.GetAccessControl().Owner}}, FullName, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime | Export-Csv $MyFile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `Select-Object` to include

```
@{N='OU';E={Get-ADUser -Identity ($_.GetAccessControl().Owner) -Properties Canonicalname | select -ExpandProperty Canonicalname}}
```

The `CanonicalName` property gives you the path to the User eg: `domain.com/Users/James`, the other alternative is using `DistinguishedName` will return `CN=James,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com`

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.  Before I had my code similar to SteloNLD's response below but realized I was over complicating things.  Shortened it to a one liner.  This code does not retrieve any data when adding to mine but it does get me on the right track.  Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you mean with OU Group but if you mean OU then try using something like the following code, you can add other things to.

```
#Settings
$Path = "$($env:USERPROFILE)\Documents"
$OutputFile = Join-Path $Path "test.csv"

#Vars
$Files  = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse
$Export = @()

#Loop
Foreach ($File in $Files) {
    $Owner = $File.GetAccessControl().Owner 

    $ADUser = Get-ADUser ($Owner -replace ".*\\", "") -Properties mail, department, Canonicalname        

    $Export += $File | Select-Object @{N='Owner';E={$_.GetAccessControl().Owner}}, `
                                        @{N='Owner-FullName';E={$ADUser.Name}}, `
                                        @{N='Owner-Department';E={$ADUser.Derparmtent}}, `
                                        @{N='Owner-OU';E={($ADUser.Canonicalname -split '/')[((($ADUser.Canonicalname -split '/').count)-2)]}}, `
                                        @{N='Owner-Mail';E={$ADUser.Mail}}, `
                                        FullName, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime    
}

#Export
$Export | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```